# How do I analyse my website in terms of SEO?

Tags: seo, analytics

What are the tools that can be used to analyse the SEO score and other SEO factors that helps in promoting websites in search engines?

Answer (score 2):

There are many free tools available in the market but the favorite one are Google chrome /Mozilla addon some of them are

1. [Yahoos Yslow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/)
2. [SEO Doctor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/seo-doctor/)
3. Google Webmaster tools(not a browser addon)
4. Google Page Speed

Comment: i found google webmaster and SEOMoz good

Comment: The tools mentioned here are pretty good - and free. Don't buy a software or service, you can get for free!
[Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) is a good starting point. And really make use of Yslow or comparable tools, as Google also ranks based on the page-load-speed.

Comment: Correct. Yslow is based on the FireBug efoxtension for Firefox. Google's PageSpeed is also a very valuable resource in finding bottlenecks on your pages. Another good SEO-only plugin for Firefox would be SEOquake!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more complete suite of tools I would take a look at [Raven Tools](http://raventools.com) and/or [SEOMoz Pro](http://www.seomoz.org/plans) - they both cost you a bit of money but they contain excellent tools and provide great ways to track your website's SEO effectiveness over time.