# How to reverse engineer the SEO on a website?

Tags: seo, analytics, optimization

I have read [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/how-do-i-analyse-my-website-in-terms-of-seo) question. My question is a bit different from it. I want to know how can I reverse engineer another website that is ranking the best for some keywords. For example some website called `example.com` is there and it ranks high for many keywords and I want to learn from it how can my website be of the same authority and get the same ranking (or probably better ranking if I found something that they are missing). Can anyone enlist it as a procedure, how to **reverse engineer** a website?

Answer (score 2):

Use alexa.com. Does your competitor have 7,000 ***quality*** links? Then that's **why** they rank. Otherwise, you'll just have to *guess* based on the keywords on the page. Use those keywords too and use good SEO practice in general. **Be Warned**: Copying their website (including a paragraph or 2) will greatly reduce your ranking. Google penalizes duplicate content.

Also the length of time a website has been online matters. Did your competitor get a head start? Then it's gonna be hard to unseat them without many more quality links.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SEOmoz's Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/) to analyze how your site is faring against a competitor on multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.majesticseo.com/ to check all the targeted website links, and the new links timeline. Then optimize yours to beat him. (Caution, aged domain always get a special boost in rankings)